# Using Fabric in Python

Tags: python, fabric

I have installed Fabric on Python2.6 using pip, and it has created two directories:

```
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/fabfile
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/fabric
```

When I initially ran the $ fab command it said "command not found". Then I made sure my system path included both folders, and still I got "command not found". Furthermore, I looked in each folder and could not find the `fab` file or directory.

Note: I can do this from the Python prompt

```
>>> from fabric.api import ...
```

What do I need to do to be able to execute the `$ fab` command? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executives like this are usually not copied to your library folder of python (so not in site-packages). In Ubuntu this one is for example copied into `/usr/bin` which is in the PATH. I don't know though were it is in your case (since it is not automatically in your PATH). So all you can do is search for `fab` in your file system.

PS: 
That you can import fabric in your python interpreter is correct, since the python library (in your site-packages) is in your PATH, though as said, the file to execute `fab` is somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

I did exactly what Torsen saids and it works for me.

```
sudo find / | grep "fab"
```

I found `fab` file at `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/fab` on Mac OS X.

Comment: Mine was hiding in /local/bin/fab (Elementary OS Luna), but was looking in /usr/bin/fab: No such file or directory . Added location to path and works. Thanks!